# Is there a particular order when evaluating the complex exponential?

Tags: complex-numbers

This question might seem silly. But I just cannot get this:

$e^{i 6\pi} = 1+0i$

($e^{i 6\pi})^{1/2} = \sqrt{1+0i} = \sqrt{1} = 1$

($e^{i 6\pi})^{1/2} = e^{i3\pi} = -1+0i = -1$

Comment: The fun lies with $\sqrt{}$, I think $\sqrt{1}$ could also be -1, which makes sense.

Comment: both cases you have the possibility of being $\pm 1$ but matching them up to one another is a different matter..it is usually based on convention rather than procedure.

Comment: Oh, this is an old friend $x^{2} = a$ and $x = \pm\sqrt{a} $